# Flutters resource load faster than native Android

Tags: android, flutter, bitmap, drawable

I'm trying to convert image taken from resources to ByteArray which 
will later be send through Socket. I've been measuring time of each of this conversion.

I've done it on both Flutter and native Android (Kotlin). All of the test were done on the same image which was about 1-2MB.

Flutter code :

```
 sendMessage() async {
    if (socket != null) {
      Stopwatch start = Stopwatch()..start();
      final imageBytes = await rootBundle.load('assets/images/stars.jpg');
      final image = base64Encode(imageBytes.buffer.asUint8List(imageBytes.offsetInBytes, imageBytes.lengthInBytes));
      print('Converting took ${start.elapsedMilliseconds}');
      socket.emit("message", [image]);
    }
  }
```

Kotlin code:

```
 private fun sendMessage() {
        var message = ""
        val thread = Thread(Runnable {
            val start = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
            val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.stars)
            message = Base64.encodeToString(getBytesFromBitmap(bitmap), Base64.DEFAULT)
            Log.d("Tag", "Converting time was : ${SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - start}")
        })
        thread.start()
        thread.join()
        socket.emit("message", message)
    }

  private fun getBytesFromBitmap(bitmap: Bitmap): ByteArray? {
        val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream)
        return stream.toByteArray()
  }
```

I've been actually expecting native code to be much much faster than Flutter's but thats not the case.. Conversion for Flutter takes about 50ms and its around 2000-3000ms for native. 
I thought that Threading may be the case, so I've tried to run this conversion on background thread for native code but it didn't help. 
Can you please tell me why is there such a different in time, and how I can implement it better in native code? Is there a way to omit casting to Bitmap etc.? Maybe this makes it so long.

EDIT. Added getBytesFromBitmap function

Comment: try `BitmapFactory` instead of `getDrawable()` - but i wouldnt expect much difference

Comment: Now I may be wrong, but I think theres actually a lot going on when you 'use native Android': it looks through all the resources for the one you want, it finds its location and loads into a bytearray, it builds a bitmap from that bytearray, it packages that bitmap into a drawable, then it extracts it again, possibly making copies left and right in the process, then converts it back into a buffer, possibly losing some quality along the way depending on what is the default bitmap encoding. And even then 3000ms for a 2mb image is a lot. It shouldnt take this long. I'm sure theres a way to load a

Comment: @pskink It didn't change anything :(

Comment: post your code then (the one using `BitmapFactory`)

Comment: I've edited post and moved conversion to another Thread

Comment: and how else I can send image?

Comment: and the difference is that in flutter you just read your data without any [image](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Image-class.html) decoding, while in kotlin you are first decoding to `Bitmap` and then you are compressing it back

Comment: Ok, so what should I use to read data without image decoding on native? Is that possible?

Comment: try `Resources#openRawResource()` and read its `InputStream` in a loop

Comment: OK! I've done `val array = resources.openRawResource(+R.drawable.stars).readBytes()` and now it takes about 50ms to convert an image! THANK YOU so much!
If you would like, create an answer and I'll mark it as correct one :)

Comment: sure, your welcome - btw nice feature of kotlin - `readBytes()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the difference you see is that in flutter code you just read your data without any image decoding, while in kotlin you are first decoding to `Bitmap` and then you are `compress()`ing it back - if you want to speed it up simply get an `InputStream` by calling `Resources#openRawResource` and read your image resource without any decoding

Answer (score 0):

It have something to do with the way you convert it to bytes... Can you please post your 
getBytesFromBitmap func? Plus, the conversion in native code really should be done in background thread, please upload the your results in this case.

Comment: Yes sorry about that, changed the post